# How to wait for user to press enter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a value that needs to be converted to str() and then int() after the user has input and press enter. It keeps trying to convert nothing as user input has not happened yet:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

month = StringVar()
combobox = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable = month)
combobox.pack()
combobox.config(values = ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'))
year = StringVar()
Spinbox(root, from_ = 1990, to = 2014, textvariable = year).pack()
yearstr = str(year)
yearcheck = int(yearstr)
if yearcheck >= 1990 and yearcheck < 2014:
    tkMessageBox.SelectedDate("Date Selector", "The date you have selected is ", str(month), ", ", str(year))
else:
    tkMessageBox.DateError("Date Selector", "Year must be 1990-2014")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: your question is about `tkinter` right? else you could do `input()` but in a GUI context that would be bad.

Comment: tkinter's `mainloop()` handled keypresses. You need to write event handling code that does the conversions you need, and attach that code to the widget(s) involved—typically by adding a `command=my_function` keyword argument to the widget's constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`root.mainloop()` is the code that does the waiting, you shouldn't add an explicit wait.

The way GUI programs work is that you set *bindings* that link user actions to functions. For example, if you want to do something when the user presses the enter key, you set a binding for `<Return>` which will call a function when the user presses enter.

For example:

```
def handle_enter(event):
   <do your validation here>

spinbox = Spinbox(root, from_ = 1990, to = 2014, textvariable = year)
spinbox.pack()  
spinbox.bind("<Return>", handle_enter)
```

Note:

1. To use the value of a `StringVar` you must call `get` on the instance (eg: year.get()`) rather than calling`str(year)`.
2. You shouldn't both create the widget and call `pack` on one line. While it's harmless when you don't need to keep a reference to the widget (as in your original code), it won't work if you need to keep a reference. The reason is that in python, `x=y().z()` gives the value of `z()` to `x`, so `spinbox = Spinbox(...).pack()` sets the value of `spinbox` to  the result of `pack()` which will always be `None`.

Here is a complete working example, though I've modified it slightly to adhere to best practices (grouping calls to `pack` together, not doing a wildcard import, fixing incorrect usage of messagebox):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

def handle_enter(event):
    yearstr = year.get()
    monthstr = month.get()
    yearcheck = int(yearstr)

    if yearcheck >= 1990 and yearcheck < 2014:
        tk.messagebox.showwarning("Date Selector", 
                                  "The date you have selected is %s, %s" % (monthstr, yearstr))
    else:
        tk.messagebox.showwarning("Date Selector", "Year must be 1990-2014")


root = tk.Tk()

month = tk.StringVar()
year = tk.StringVar()

combobox = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable = month)
combobox.config(values = ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'))
spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, from_ = 1990, to = 2014, textvariable = year)

combobox.pack()
spinbox.pack()

spinbox.bind("<Return>", handle_enter)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Very helpful, I'm still learning tkinter and was playing around with adding regular commands with tkinter. Didn't know how it integrated with tkinter but now I do. :)